# I am getting the the "Error detected while processing ~/vimrc" while writing c++ on Vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I want to use c++ on vim but i am getting the vimrc error

```
" use vim settings, rather than vi settings. this setting must be as
early as
" possible, as it has side effects. this is required for vundle.
set nocompatible
filetype off

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" add other plugins here...
Plugin 'jamessan/vim-gnupg'
Bundle 'croaky/vim-colors-github'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()               " required
filetype plugin indent on       " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
~                    

$ vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/tridip/.vimrc:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: early as
line    9:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
line   15:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'jamessan/vim-gnupg'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'croaky/vim-colors-github'
line   19:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: FYI - https://vi.stackexchange.com/ for questions about Vi and Vim.

Answer (score 3):

```
Error detected while processing /home/tridip/.vimrc:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: early as
```

It looks like you've pasted in some text into your `.vimrc` and there are unwanted line breaks, so that this text which should be part of the previous line is on its own line:

```
early as
```

This is not a valid vim command, so it causes an error.

Open your `.vimrc` and either add a `"` character to line 2, or go to line 1 and press <kbd>J</kbd> to join the lines.

```
line    9:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
```

This suggests that the vundle files are not installed in `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` -- if you want to use those files you need them to be installed!